# I have to write an automation script

Tags: linux, unix, jboss, automation, admin

I have to backup and delete old log files every month. I will delete files older than 6 months and backup files older than 2 months in as a zip file.
I am trying to write a script that will automate and do it every month instead of me doing it manually every time.
I have UNIX commands on how to do it, but I need to put it into script file which will run automatically on the day specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule a cronJob for daily , which runs command inside script such as

```
 find foldername -mtime +120 -name "*.log" -exec gzip {} \;
```

Above will take care of archiving all files older than 120  days. Part inside quotes after name can be modified as per your requirement and so does the +120.

```
find foldername -mtime +180 -name "*" -exec rm {} \;
```

Above will remove all file inside foldername older than 180 days.

For automation part , you can look at wiki link provided in the answer below. Though i will include it in my answer too.

You can use crontab to schedule commands (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: If things are helpful , we say it by up voting answers on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use crontab to schedule commands (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

You can add entry typing crontab -e and use it to schedule jobs, after adding your unix commands to a script.

For example, if you have a /home/test/test.sh file, you can run it everyday by adding the below to your crontab :

```
0 0 * * * /home/test/test.sh
```